# Search in a text file from one symbol to another

Tags: c#, regex, forms, search, text

I am coding program, and stacked. Please can give me a code which search text in file from one specific symbol to another using C# visual Windows Forms , not console application. Like this text in textfile c:\id.txt

> The entry was successfully copied to {ea4c4653-cc65-11e1-a2fc-001e101f4e71}.

search string from { to } , and result with { and }, without . at the end. And send found text in a message box.Code to search text in a file an send whole line in message box. But i need part of line.

Comment: What about `Regular expressions`?

Comment: What have you tried? This isn't a code request site, but we will help you figure out the code yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`Regex`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx) can be useful:

```
MessageBox.Show(
          Regex.Match(inputString, "\{(?<path>[^}]*)\}").Groups["path"].Value);
```

explain:

```
{        '{'

[^}]*    any character except: '}' 
         (0 or more times, matching the most amount possible)

}        '}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by using [`regular expressions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx):

```
var line = "    The entry was successfully copied to {ea4c4653-cc65-11e1-a2fc-001e101f4e71}.";
var foo = Regex.Match(line, @"to\s*\{([^}]+)\}");
if(foo.Success) {
    MessageBox.Show(foo.Groups[1].Value); //ea4c4653-cc65-11e1-a2fc-001e101f4e71
} else {
   //not found value 
}
```